# Zend Cache Static directory configuration in Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: caching, zend-framework, config

How can I configure temporary directory for Zend Cache (Zend Cache Static)?

Now it tries to save the files to `/` and I get the `open_basedir` restriction in effect.

I use Zend Application with `application.ini` file config. ZF v 1.11

Maybe I need to set the default tmp dir somewhere in the server config files? (Plesk panel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this globally by setting [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) php configuration variable (in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`).